# Failing to build connection with server folder using SMBConnection

Tags: python, smb, wireguard, pysmb

I am trying to connect to a server folder which is only accessible through Wireguard VPN. I installed the VPN, and created the `wg-config.conf` file and currently, I am able to connect via `Finder` on my Mac. Here is the access address: `smb://10.0.0.1/Folder_X`
Here is my `wg-config.conf` file contents:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <my private key>
Address = 10.0.0.16/21

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public key>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/33
Endpoint = 514.58.69.221:51620
```

Now, I am trying to build the connection to this server Folder_X using Python, as I need to access the folder, fetch the files, and do some processing. Here's my code which returns `timed out` error and fails to connect.

```
import time
import subprocess
import requests
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
from config import Config
import socket

server_ip = '514.58.69.221'
remote_port = '51620'
shared_folder_path = '/Folder_X'
# Generating WireGuard configuration file
Config()

# Connect to server and fetch data
subprocess.run(['wg-quick', 'up', './wg-config.conf'])

remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(server_ip)

# Establish a connection to the remote server
conn = SMBConnection(Config.USERNAME, Config.PASSWORD, '', remote_ip, use_ntlm_v2=True)
try:
    print(f"Connecting to server {server_ip}:{remote_port}")
    conn.connect(remote_ip, int(remote_port))
    print("Connected to server successfully")

    # Retrieve the list of files from the shared folder
    file_list = conn.listPath('IPC$', shared_folder_path)

    # Print the list of files
    print("Files in the shared folder:")
    for file in file_list:
        print(file.filename)

    # Disconnect from the server
    conn.close()
    print("Disconnected from the server")

except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to connect to the server:", str(e))
```

My gut tells me there is a simple mistake somewhere that I am not able to see.